# How can I add an AdminPermission to my plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I've created a RCP application with a plugin that requires to invoke the method `Bundle.findEntries`. In debugging mode (i.e., when I launch my app from eclipse) everything works correctly, but when I run the "real" application (i.e., I export the RCP app and I run it) the method stops working and returns null.

From the documentation I read that the method returns null "*if the caller does not have the appropriate AdminPermission[this,RESOURCE], and the Java Runtime Environment supports permissions.*"

How can I grant such permission to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running with a Security Manager installed, then you will need to grant permissions to each bundle. The ConditionalPermissionAdmin service is the best way.

If you are not running with a Security Manager, them permissions are not being evaluated.

Comment: Actually, I did not tell my rcp app to use any kind of security manager, but I think that the production enviroment for eclipse's rcp / p2  requires it, hence I do not want to disable it and I would instead configure the permissions of my app... Do you have any link to a tutorial / guide / whatever about ConditionalPermissionAdmin?

Comment: As you said, permissions are not being evaluated without a permission manager... and with some debugging within the eclipse's code I found that the problem was not a misconfigured security policy ,

Comment: As you said, permissions are not being evaluated without a permission manager... and with some debugging within the eclipse's code I found that the problem was not a misconfigured security policy... (but the effects of my error was not documented in the javadoc)

Comment: So what was the problem you found?  I'm hitting the same issue.